# Add a cell from two or more rows in the same MySql table

Tags: mysql

I have x rows of a column value and "simply" want to add them together and update the highest row number and zero out the other values:

```
SELECT rowId, addCol FROM table WHERE rowId=1 OR rowId=2
```

**rowId** |  **addCol**
1         | 100
2         | 200
3         | 67

This is kind of what I want (I know it's completely wrong) but not sure how to express it!

```
UPDATE table SET addCol3=addCol1+addCol2+addCol3, addCol1=0, addCol2=0
```

**rowId** |  **addCol**
1         | 0
2         | 0
3         | 367

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table t1
JOIN table t2 ON (t1.rowId > t2.rowId)
LEFT OUTER JOIN table t3 ON (t1.rowId < t3.rowId)
SET t1.addCol = t1.addCol + t2.addCol,
    t2.addCol = 0
WHERE t3.rowId IS NULL;
```

Explanation: any SQL expression that references more than one row should be done with a `JOIN`.  In this case, we want `t1` to be the row that has no greater `rowId` in any other row.  If `t1` has the greatest `rowId`, this means `t3` would find no matching row, and therefore `t3` would be NULL.

Now that we know `t1` has the greatest `rowId`, match that to all other rows (`t2`) with a lesser `rowId`.  Zero out the `t2` value after adding it to the cumulative total in `t1`.

Comment: Is there a quick way of testing the result of what this will do without actually updating the table?

Comment: This worked as I've described but it updates all rows in the table, instead of selecting the specific ones I wanted... I've extended it a little and works perfectly, thanks!